# Bitnami MEAN stack on Mac: Unknown command express

Tags: mean-stack, bitnami

I installed MEAN stack using Bitnami installer https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/infrastructure/mean/

It is installed with all ok status. But while creating a sample project as specified in https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/infrastructure/mean/get-started/get-started/, I am getting error with `express sample`.

I am trying in my local machine [MacBook].

Is there any specific thing I am missing while setting up stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitnami developer here,

Try this:

- Load the environment (by default, installdir is `/Applications/meanstack-VERSION`):

```
cd installdir
./use_meanstack
```

- Create a new MEAN project:

```
mkdir projects
cd projects
express sample
cd sample
npm install
```

I hope it helps